# Segmentation error when getting product from repository

Tags: magento2.3, php-7

I have a test script which should update products:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$file = __DIR__.'/import.xlsx';

$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file);
/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);
$workSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $workSheet->getHighestRow();
echo 'Highest row: '.$highestRow.PHP_EOL;
$row =3;

while($row <= $highestRow){
    echo 'Entering loop '.$row.PHP_EOL;
    if(trim($workSheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue())):
        echo 'Getting value '.trim($workSheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue()).PHP_EOL;
        $childIds = [];
        try {

            $product = $productRepository->get(trim($workSheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue()));
            echo 'Getting product '.trim($workSheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue()).PHP_EOL;

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
            $product = null;
            echo $e->getMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $product = null;
        }
        .....
}
```

the console output using gdb is following:

```
Starting program: /usr/local/php74/bin/php ./testr.php
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Highest row: 212
Entering loop 3
Getting value Anza Radiatorkwast Extra

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000076f6ef in mysqlnd_mysqlnd_pfc_receive_pub (pfc=0x7fffecaa4500, vio=0x7fffecb4fc80, buffer=0x7fffff7ff020 "", count=4, conn_stats=0x7fffecbab7e0, error_info=0x7fffa2089920)
    at /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/php-7.4.33/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_protocol_frame_codec.c:319
319 /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/php-7.4.33/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_protocol_frame_codec.c: No such file or directory.
```

as you can see from output the script halts at:
**$product = $productRepository->get(trim($workSheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue()));**

any idea what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

> The code might be halting at this point because there could be a
> problem with the get method or the data that is being passed to it.

> For example, the identifier may not exist in the repository, or there
> could be an error in the database connection or query.

Comment: This does work:

`$factory = $productFactory->create();`

`$product = $factory->loadByAttribute('sku', trim($workSheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue()));`